# Word VBA - check if cursor is between two bookmarks

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I am working on Macro in Word (it also uses Excel, but nvm) and I need to check if cursor is currently between two specific bookmarks.

To be honest I have no idea how to approach the problem. I used google, I used stackoverflow search and found nothing on this topic. It is my first VBA for Word.

Please understand, that I do not provide any code - as I said, no idea how to try to write it and my research returned no results.

Comment: in which way you want to point which bookmarks should be considered? by writing it's name?

Comment: Exactly, giving their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will return False or True as a result of checking if the beginning of your selection is between 2 bookmarks passed by name to the function. It doesn't matter in which order you pass bookmarks name.

```
Function BetweenBookmarks(FirstBookmarkName, SecondBookmarkName)

    If Selection.Start > ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(FirstBookmarkName).Range.End _
        And _
        Selection.End < ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(SecondBookmarkName).Range.Start Then

            BetweenBookmarks = True

    ElseIf Selection.Start > ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(SecondBookmarkName).Range.End _
        And _
        Selection.End < ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(FirstBookmarkName).Range.Start Then

            BetweenBookmarks = True
    Else

            BetweenBookmarks = False
    End If
End Function
```

Function can be called in this way:

```
Debug.Print BetweenBookmarks("First", "Second")
Debug.Print BetweenBookmarks("Second", "First")
```

You could make some other modification on your own by changing `.End` and `.Start` properties within the function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know, that I could use > and < reffering to ranges!

Comment: Done! I was in a hurry today and I am new here.